# Populate column with different types of cells in winforms DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a model `class` and I want to populate a column for each `object` of this `class` in a `DataGriView`. The `datagridview.DataSource` populates it automatically but the thing I want is to insert the properties of the `class object` in the `rows`, not in the `columns`.

Here is a sample code for the class:

```
private void gridData_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) 
{ 
  Point point = gridData.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)); 
  int row = gridData.HitTest(point.X, point.Y).RowIndex; 
  int col = gridData.HitTest(point.X, point.Y).ColumnIndex; 
  Column draggedColumn= new Column() 
  { 
     Index = columnCount, 
     Header = string.Format("col {0}",col), 
     Description = "change descr", 
     SmartRounding = false, 
     PredefinedFunctionSelected = "select func", 
     CustomFunction = "add custom func", 
  }; 
tableGrid.Add(columnCount, draggedColumn); 
}
```

and I want to display column for each `draggedTagColumn` not a row. `tableGrid.Add(columnCount, draggedColumn)` is a dictionary I keep for other purposes. As you can see the column is not even populated with some specific data but with some default values.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to populate properties of an object then it will be easier to use `PropertyGrid` or [Devexpress's `VerticalGrid`](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Vertical_Grid/) instead of `DataGridView`.